# certain query pattern search whole database

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to find a pattern of tables (Oracle DB) starting with for example ABC in the whole schemas ,may be i explain with the better example

**ABC** - refers to for example stage schema
**ABC**_CUST_ORDER_INFO

but the problem i am currently facing is in the database i have many schemas and tables, and most of the tables some times starts with **ABC**,**BBC**,**XYZ** and so on ... this is very confusing ,
so

Query -  if a come up with a query which is flexible enough to recursively fetch the schema name, pattern counts

Pattern - starting with like wild character search

```
STAGE      PATTERN COUNT
DWH_STAGE  ABC    1000
DWH_STAGE  NBC     200
DWH_STAGE  XYZ     150
DWH_EDW    HSS     2001
DWH_EDW    DGS     300
```

2. i also need a separate query - i have various tables in the same schema like ending with **_D** ,**_F** ,**_T**,**_W**,**_V** or any such patterns so that i can flexibly use

Examples - Tables

```
ABC_CUST_ORDER_INFO_D
ABC_CUST_ADD_INFO_F
ABC_SHPNG_STTS_V
BBC_PRDCT_CRNT_VALUE_W
BBC_PRDCT_CRNT_SALE_T
CNN_PAYMT_INFO_F
```

so if a query which show no of tables ending with the able mentioned (_D ,_F ,_T,_W,_V or any such patterns)

can you please suggest ?

I have tried using multiple ways

Option 1) using wild character search

```
select * from <tbl> where col_name like 'ABC%'
where schema='schema_name'
union
select * from <tbl> where col_name like 'BBC%'
where schema='schema_name'
```

but i have at least 100+ starting with like ABC_,BBC_,XZY_ seems this option is to complicated

Option 2) using REGEXP_SUBSTR

```
SELECT
    colname,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col3, '%col3\{(.*?)\}', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS colname
FROM tblname;
```

i have tried it's not working

for example .let's consider

Table - CUST_ORDER_INFO

```
COL 1 - SCHEMA_NAME - DWH_STAGE (record)
COL 2 - CUST_ORDER_INFO (record)
COL 3 - CUST_INFO - ABC_CUST_ORDER_INFO (record)
```

SAMPLE RECORDS  - ABC_CUST_ORDER_INFO,BBC_PRDCT_CRNT_VALUE_W

so the expected result is like this

```
SCHEMA_NAME CUST_ORDER_INFO CUST_INFO               PATTERN  COUNT
DWH_STAGE   SHOES           ABC_CUST_ORDER_INFO     ABC      1000
DWH_STAGE   SHOES           BBC_PRDCT_CRNT_VALUE_W  BBC      300
```

Comment: Something like `select owner, count(*) from dba_tables where table_name like 'ABC%' group by owner order by owner`?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Many thanks for your response , that is fine it can be done in seperate filters but iteratively using flexible procedure some thing like that , but how can we run iteratively ,since there are 1) Many patterns not only ABC 2) There are also many schemas as well thats the difficulty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will look for tables in the database that begin with **XXX_...** and group them together by the prefix and schema:

```sql
  SELECT owner AS schema_name, SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 3) AS beginning, COUNT (*) AS COUNT
    FROM dba_tables
   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (table_name, '^[[:alpha:]]{3}_')
GROUP BY owner, SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 3)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

This query will do the same thing but grouping by the last character for tables that end in **..._X**

```sql
  SELECT owner AS schema_name, SUBSTR (table_name, -1) AS ending, COUNT (*) AS COUNT
    FROM dba_tables
   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (table_name, '_[[:alpha:]]$')
GROUP BY owner, SUBSTR (table_name, -1)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

You can modify either query to just look at tables in a specific schema if you'd like.

Comment: Many thanks EJ Egyed for the logic ,Excellent Awesome